# How to adapt Left Join and Sub Queries to Fix incorrect SUMS when using Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble getting the correct Summed results on my query.  I'm trying to sum up all results by person, by type of work by date.  When I run my query in its entirety, my SUM results are astronomical.

The tables and fields I'm using are: Operators (OprExtID) and vwProductionDataForTouchReporting (Opr, Extract).  Note, I removed the tables/fields and joins that allow grouping "by type of work" temporarily as these joins were causing my high sum numbers.

Before I add those joins back in I think I need to sum up my results using a subquery but am running into an error when I attempt it.

I'm getting an "Incorrect syntax near '.'." error.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(OP.OprExtID,'_CSIMAGS') AS Processor, Convert(VARCHAR(8), VT.StartDateTime, 112) AS [Processed Date], VT.Extract AS [Completed]
FROM dbo.Operators OP
INNER JOIN (SELECT OP.Operator, SUM(dbo.VT.Extract) as Completed
FROM VT GROUP BY VT.OPR) dbo.vwProductionDataForTouchReporting VT
ON OP.Operator = VT.Opr
GROUP BY VT.EXTRACT, CONCAT(OP.OprExtID,'_CSIMAGS'), Convert(VARCHAR(8), VT.StartDateTime, 112)
```

As an example: Using the following results I would expect the query to give me the below results:

Example Table Operator:
OprExtID 
0012385

Example Table (View) vwProductionDataForTouchReporting
StartDateTime,Opr,Extract
2019-01-03,0012385,15
2019-01-03,0012385,87
2019-01-04,0012385,12
2019-01-04,0012385,7

Query Results:
Processed Date,Processor,Completed
2019-01-03,0012385,102
2019-01-04,0012385,19

Any tips on what I'm missing here?

Comment: You should really simplify your problem to two or three tables, along with sample data and desired results.  The general solution, though, is to aggregate *before* joining.

Comment: Impossible to help you without sample data and expected results.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running on?

Comment: This server is running SQL 2016 SP2 CU4 Enterprise.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, that's what I'm aiming to do, is aggregate prior to joining, it's just applying the subqueries appropriately and knowing which joins I need to switch from INNER to LEFTs.  The problem I think lies in the VT table I'm referencing as that's where the Extract column results are coming from.  I'm not sure if I'm interpreting your simplification statement correctly though.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the catch.  I added in example data of what's written in the VT View/Table, the values in the Extract field of which should be output in the query results.  I also listed the current query results for the same person/date.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain your join is correct the way you have written it (or maybe I misinterpret what you are trying to do here). I would write this a little differently:

```
FROM ((((dbo.Operators AS OP
 INNER JOIN dbo.vwProductionDataForTouchReporting VT
 ON OP.Operator = VT.Opr)
 INNER JOIN dbo.DataInput DI
 ON VT.JobID = DI.JobID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.jobs JO
 ON DI.JobID = JO.ID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.Machines MA
 ON DI.MachNo = MA.MachNo)
 INNER JOIN dbo.JobTypes JT
 ON DI.JobTypeID = JT.JobTypeID
```

This is usually how I see joins being coded:

```
FROM dbo.Operators AS OP
INNER JOIN dbo.vwProductionDataForTouchReporting VT
 ON (OP.Operator = VT.Opr)
 INNER JOIN dbo.DataInput DI
 ON (VT.JobID = DI.JobID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.jobs JO
 ON (DI.JobID = JO.ID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.Machines MA
 ON (DI.MachNo = MA.MachNo)
 INNER JOIN dbo.JobTypes JT
 ON (DI.JobTypeID = JT.JobTypeID)
```

Also if you are in fact getting duplicates then you can run your query against an aggregate table (a few ways to do it but you can literally put a select in place of a table reference):

```
FROM dbo.Operators AS OP
INNER JOIN (SELECT top 1 Opr from dbo.vwProductionDataForTouchReporting) VT
 ON (OP.Operator = VT.Opr)
 INNER JOIN dbo.DataInput DI
 ON (VT.JobID = DI.JobID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.jobs JO
 ON (DI.JobID = JO.ID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.Machines MA
 ON (DI.MachNo = MA.MachNo)
 INNER JOIN dbo.JobTypes JT
 ON (DI.JobTypeID = JT.JobTypeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having doesn't have anything to do with how many tables you're joining to. The issue is that in one or more of those tables, there are more records than you think there are based on the `JOIN` criteria you're specifying.

We don't have your table schemas or sample data, so you're unlikely to get a specific answer here, but you can get to the bottom of this yourself.

Start with just one table and get a row count:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.Operators AS OP
--INNER JOIN
--    dbo.vwProductionDataForTouchReporting AS VT
--      ON
--      OP.Operator = VT.Opr
--INNER JOIN
--    dbo.DataInput AS DI
--      ON
--      VT.JobID = DI.JobID
--INNER JOIN
--    dbo.jobs AS JO
--      ON
--      DI.JobID = JO.ID
--INNER JOIN
--    dbo.Machines AS MA
--      ON
--      DI.MachNo = MA.MachNo
--INNER JOIN
--    dbo.JobTypes AS JT
--      ON
--      DI.JobTypeID = JT.JobTypeID
```

Uncomment out one `JOIN` at a time until your count runs wild. Look at what's happening on that table, and consider, perhaps, only joining to a `SUBQUERY` with a `SELECT...GROUP BY` around the columns you need. What you actually have to do will depend on what you find, but you'll know more specifically what you're dealing with.